# Comparing running processes of two linux devices

Tags: linux, bash

I have two embedded devices with identical hardware, which I am developing app for. Identical apps are running on both devices, however memory consumption is significantly larger on device A compared to  device B. I've gathered process list on both devices via:
`ps -A > psListDeviceA.txt`
and
`ps -A > psListDeviceB.txt`
Both files were transferred to fully functional Ubuntu desktop workstation. How do I compare these files so I can see which processes are running in addition on device with higher memory consumption?

Comment: `ps -A` does not report memory usage, so I don't really get what you're going for here.

Comment: @Panki I am seeking difference in running processes, not memory usage (for now). I want to see which processes are running on device B in comparsion with processes running on device A.

Comment: Sort them alphabetically (strip away the PID) and use `diff` or `comm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this,

```
ps -o pid,user,%mem,command ax > FileDeviceA
```

and

```
ps -o pid,user,%mem,command ax > FileDeviceB
```

to get the procceses on both devices with memory.
To take a look at the difference and sort it use

```
diff FileDeviceA FileDeviceB | sort -b -k3 -r.
```

Good luck with your application.